Bad state: cannot add new events after calling close with google sign in
I'm trying to sign in with google in my flutter application. _getHome() calls content state and its content in home view model page..and signIn() logs in with google. But after logging in, I get stuck on the dispose on the home view model page. what should I do?
this is _getHome in home view model page:
_getHome() async {
    inputState.add(LoadingState(
        stateRendererType: StateRendererType.FULL_SCREEN_LOADING_STATE));
    (await _homeUseCase.execute(Void)).fold((failure) {
      inputState.add(ErrorState(
          StateRendererType.FULL_SCREEN_ERROR_STATE, failure.message));
    }, (homeObject) {
      inputState.add(ContentState());
      inputHomeData.add(
          HomeViewObject(homeObject.data.bannerads, homeObject.data.workshops));
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _dataStreamController.close();
    super.dispose();
  }

this is signIn() in login page:
Future signIn() async {
    var user = await GoogleSignInApi.login();

    if (user == null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text('Giriş basarısız')));
    } else {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
        _appPreferences.setMember(user.email!);
        _appPreferences.setIsUserLoggedIn();
          Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed(Routes.mainRoute);
      });
    }
  }

